# apply JavaScript to all elements with id

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a id="link" href="http://www.google.co.uk">link</a>

<a id="link" href="http://stackoverflow.com">link</a>
```

the javascript only replaces the first `href` but i want it to apply to any and all `<a>` with the `id="link"` **OR** do you have a **jQuery** alternative?

```
<script>
var link = document.getElementById('link');
var src = link.getAttribute('href');
var paramurl = encodeURIComponent(src);
link.setAttribute("href", "http://mysite.com/?url=" + paramurl);
</script>
```

Comment: There should be only ***one*** element with any given `id`. If you have multiple elements sharing a name, then use a `class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a class-name instead of an `id`:

```
<a class="link" href="http://www.google.co.uk">link</a>

<a class="link" href="http://stackoverflow.com">link</a>
```

With the JavaScript:

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('link');
for (i=0;i<links.length;i++){
    var src = links[i].getAttribute('href');
    var paramurl = encodeURIComponent(src);
    links[i].setAttribute('href','http://mysite.com/?url=' + paramurl);
    /* or, preferably:
    links[i].href = 'http://mysite.com/?url=' + paramurl;
    */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rLnFS/).

Answer (score 0):

use classes instead

```
<a class="link" href="http://www.google.co.uk">link</a>

<a class="link" href="http://stackoverflow.com">link</a>
```

and change the `href` attr like

```
$("a.link").each(function(){
var src = $(this).attr("href");
var paramurl = encodeURIComponent(src);
$(this).attr("href","http://mysite.com/?url="+paramurl);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qxCdH/)

Comment: He want's to use ID's for some weird reason, and there is a way. One moment

Comment: I know. But it is still possible

Comment: My example works the same as your, but with ID's, Pleas check it out.

Comment: @JonahAllibone no it does not hover over the `link2` and see the url only one url gets encoded...

Comment: Please check what you just said. I am pretty sure it does, I just checked.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T4h2W/3/ That is my final word. That works with ID's and I am positive.

Comment: Please don't argue the point. Duplicate ID's should NEVER be used. Ever. It's not valid HTML. If someone asks for code that works with duplicate IDs, it's better to teach them and explain why they should use classes, instead of providing an incorrect but working solution using duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have more than one element with the same id on a page.  If you want to apply a javascript function to more than one element at the same time, you should use the class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The better is use classes, but with id can be:

```
$(function () {
        $('a[id=link]').each(function () {
            var link = 'http://something' + $(this).attr('href');
            $(this).attr('href', link);
        });
    });
```

Comment: My answer is nearly identical, but I use the encode he wants. Please look at it above yours, it has a jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

A complementary solution. I have a table with many records (tr's), when I change the value with id="fecharendicion", the script changes all registers with the class="new_date".

```
<input id="fecharendicion" name="0" type="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" />

<script>
   $(document.body).on('change','#fecharendicion', function() {          
   var fecha = $('#fecharendicion').val();
   $('.new_date').val(fecha);
   });
</script>

...
<tr>
  <td><input name="{{a.first.id}}" type="date" class="form-control new_date" /></td>
</tr>
...
```

Answer (score -1):

use the jQuery `$.each` method to apply changes to each separate `<a>` tag. Here is a working example:

#### [http://jsfiddle.net/T4h2W/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/T4h2W/3/)

Comment: Whomever voted this down, please understand that I my example works, and works correctly. If you doubt me, please visit my link and notice it works. Thank you

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but would suggest it was likely because you're showing how to use JavaScript to manipulate invalid HTML. Because it's invalid it may break as and when JavaScript engines are updated (and HTML 5  *should* be far more strict about invalid mark-up), and will fail unpredictably. It shouldn't work, that it does is an error; and should not be supported, and certainly not encouraged.

Comment: Yes, but I answered the question

Comment: Your answer may achieve the goal of the OP, but it's still working with invalid HTML. The criteria for a down-vote is whether the answer is useful or not. It does, I agree, answer the question. It remains bad advice though.